# Hide and display plot based on one actionButton in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below which by default displays a plot. When I click the `actionButton()` it hides it but then I want to click the same `actionButton()` again and display it and so forth.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      
      actionButton("hideshow_plot",
                   "HideShow plot")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "car_plot")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  showPlot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)

 
  
  observeEvent(input$hideshow_plot, {
    showPlot(FALSE) 
  })
  
  output$car_plot <- renderPlot({
    if (showPlot()){
      plot(cars)
    }
    else{
      
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
  observeEvent(input$hideshow_plot, {
    showPlot(!showPlot()) 
  })
```

to alternate TRUE/FALSE at each click.

Answer (score 1):

Considered to use `shinyjs`?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("hideshow_plot",
                         "HideShow plot")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "car_plot")

        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$hideshow_plot, {
        shinyjs::toggle("car_plot")
    })

    output$car_plot <- renderPlot({
        plot(cars)
    })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```